# How to add a computer environment variable to a console application as a path pointer for logging

Tags: c#, logging, console-application, nlog

I created a variable on the computer and specified the path to the folder through it, then specified it in the NLog.config file

fileName="${environment:LOG_DIRECTORY}${date:format=yyyy-MM-dd}_reportlog.txt"

But the file is still being deleted in the default order. I tried to write a path in my own class, but it still doesn't help. It is necessary to set the path through the environment variable.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: What is meant by `file is still being deleted in the default order` ? Have you tried https://github.com/NLog/NLog/wiki/Logging-troubleshooting ? (Maybe your changes to `NLog.config` are not deployed)